# Django Custom Template Tags

Tags: python, django, template, html-tags

Boa tarde, recentemente estou com um problema no framework Django, estou com um problema em meu custom template tag, eu faço o método em um arquivo.py chamo ele no templates e não exibe o resultado que quero, podem dar uma olhada fazendo favor?

Seguem os arquivos:

**time_tags.py**

```
from django import template
from datetime import date

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def informa_data(value):
    today = date.today()
    weekday = today.weekday()
    if weekday == 4:
        return str(today)
    else:
        return 'nao e sexta'
```

**template.html:**

Inseri `{% load time_tags %}` logo abaixo dos:

```
{% extends 'base/base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
```

E em algum determinado lugar dentro do `<body>`:

```
<p>
     {{ instance.content|informa_data }}
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Após um diálogo, e entendendo o real problema chegamos na seguinte solução:

```
# views.py
def from_friday_to_friday(now=datetime.now()):
    days_from_friday = (now.weekday() - 4) % 7
    first_friday = now - timedelta(days=days_from_friday)
    myfridays = {
        'first_friday': first_friday,
        'second_friday': first_friday + timedelta(weeks=1)
    }
    return myfridays


def home(request):
    ctx = {'myfridays': from_friday_to_friday()}
    return render(request, 'index.html', ctx)
```

e o template

```
# index.html
<p>{{ myfridays.first_friday|date:"d/m/Y" }} à {{ myfridays.second_friday|date:"d/m/Y" }}</p>
```

Comment: Cara, o erro no seu código não é solucionado com esse código que vc colocou aí na resposta. Vc abandonou o uso da sua custom template tag em vez de corrigi-la. Achei isso meio estranho, até porque já tinham indicado onde estava o erro da sua custom template tag em outra resposta.

Answer (score 1):

acredito que o seu problema está aqui:

```
@register.filter
def informa_data(value):
    today = date.today() #MAIS PRECISAMENTE AQUI
    weekday = today.weekday()
    if weekday == 4:
        return str(today)
    else:
        return 'nao e sexta'
```

nesse código você declarou o seu filtro corretamente, o filtro recebe um valor como parametro `value` que é o valor da variável que você aplica o seu filtro no template 
`{{ instance.content|informa_data }}`.

Nesse exemplo que você colocou o valor seria o valor da variável `instance.content`.

Contudo você não está utilizando o valor que está sendo passado por parametro e utilizando o date.today(). O que faz com que o seu filtro sempre retorne se `hoje` é sexta feira ou não.